# Jquery Loader working on Chrome and not on FireFox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code for a loading spinner, it works on Chrome Android, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work on Firefox on Android.
Please assist.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#loader').hide();

  $('form').submit(function(event) {
    $('#loader').show();
  });

  $('a.withloader').click(function(event) {
    $('#loader').show();
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div id="loader" style="position: fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height: 100%; display: none; background: url('http://sampsonresume.com/labs/pIkfp.gif') center center #efefefe0; background-repeat: no-repeat; z-index:9999;"></div>

  <h1>
    Loader

  </h1>

  <form action="" method="post">
    <button type="submit">
        Submit
      </button>
  </form>

  <a href="#" class="withloader">Submit</a>
</body>
```

Comment: "it doesn't work on Firefox on Android."  But what happens? What is the error?

Comment: You aren’t preventing the form submission. I don’t think you can rely on JavaScript being executed on a page that is about to get reloaded or unloaded. Though, there is no reason it shouldn’t work when the `<a>` is clicked.

Comment: Nothing happens, no errors, it just doesn't run.

Comment: I just test on Firefox. and it works.

Comment: Did you test it on Android's FF? I even created a fiddle and the fiddle doesnt work on FF on Andriod https://jsfiddle.net/hlogi/6Lnmoq48/1/ , but works on Chrome on Android

Comment: @Andrew Lohr, I did add jquery already, that's why it runs on Chrome. Im not sure what I'm missing..